# How to find if kendoNumericTextBox already has change event bound?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendonumerictextbox

I have KendoNumericTextBox control and i am attaching 'change' event handler to it and then trying to find if it has change event handler attached. But $._data(element,'events') doesn't list 'change' event.

```
        $('#MyID')
            .getKendoNumericTextBox()
            .bind('change', function (e) {
                alert('something changed')
            })

        var ev = $._data($('#MyID')[0], 'events');
        if (ev && ev.change)
        {
            //this never gets executes even i have change event handler  attached
            alert('do something');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the kendo widget instance:

```
var numerictextbox = $("#MyID").data("kendoNumericTextBox");
```

Then look at the _events object and check for a change property:

```
alert(numerictextbox._events["change"] ? "YES" : "NO");
```

Here is a **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/eJuDO)**